# using #ifdef inside "Windows Form Designer generated code" in C++ CLI with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, designer, command-line-interface

Good afternoon,
I am having an issue trying to conditionally comment out some code sections and objects inside code that is generated by Windows Forms Designer.

If I simply comment out these objects, the designer will show no issues with the code and will display what I am working on

If I comment out with #ifdef and #endif in the code, the designer gives me
 "C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 358, Column: 1 --- Unexpected token for a 'term' "
 and will not display the UI I am working on. However the code will compile just fine without errors.

Is there a way to conditionally comment out sections of the designer code in the Form.h file?

Thanks,
-D

Comment: The forms designer doesn't call the pre-processor perhaps? Generally speaking, don't touch files that are automatically generated.

Comment: Is there a better way to conditionally comment it out, other than just placing it in comments? Is there a fix for VS2010 that allows this? Thanks,

Comment: Make the controls hidden or otherwise invisible, and have your conditional code in a source file which hides or shows depending on your conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Do **not** edit designer-generated code.  If your change works then it is not going to live long, wiped out when the designer re-generates the code.  And the real problem, the designer code parser can only understand the kind of code it generates itself.  It is not a full-blown compiler, it doesn't know beans what #ifdef might mean.  Which is what the error is trying to tell you.

If you need conditional changes then you need to make them in form's constructor, *after* the InitializeComponent() call.  You can remove or add controls and change their properties as needed.